# How do I get git worktree add to work like the example?

Tags: git

The `git add worktree` sample at the bottom of the documentation does not seem to work.  Am I doing something wrong?  I thought this commit would commit to the master branch, but it doesn't seem to.  Did they leave out a merge?

I have tried most of the git worktree add examples to find something similar to how it work in SVN, and the best I am coming up with is being able to checkout to a different directory, but only one tree.

This looks like it might work, but the commit doesn't seem to get to the master branch, which I thought was why it was specified.

From the git worktree add docs:

```
$ git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master
$ pushd ../temp
# ... hack hack hack ...
$ git commit -a -m 'emergency fix for boss'
$ popd
$ rm -rf ../temp
$ git worktree prune
```

I expected the change I made to get into the master branch, but it does not.

Comment: Just to better understand your question, why use `pushd/popd` instead of just navigating to the relevant dir with `cd`? Some specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git worktree add -b emergency-fix ../temp master
```

This adds a worktree on directory `../temp`, creating a branch named `emergency-fix` (because of `-b emergency-fix`), branching off from `master`.

If you commit in the worktree, then changes get committed to this new branch. You'll need to merge, cherry-pick, etc, the changes.

If you're working on another branch, you can create a worktree pointing to `master`.

Comment: I think I understand now.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to make it clear, `master` is a starting point because of `-b <branch-name> <starting-point>` (just as in `git checkout`). You can create a worktree pointing to master with `git worktree add <dir> master`, but `master` must not be checked in the main copy or any other worktree.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you successfully created the new working tree with the [git worktree add](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Use-this-git-worktree-add-example-and-never-switch-branches-again) command, but after doing your changes and issuing your git commit, you never merged your changes into the master branch.

The trick is to move back to the master branch and then merge the fix

```
me@machine /workspace/mine **(master)**
$ git merge emergency-fix  ## or whatever the branch name is
```

### One branch checkout at a time!

Note that you won't be able to checkout the master branch from the emergency-fix working tree if it is already open on another working tree, so you may need to actually open a bash shell in that folder to do the merge. If you have active changes going on in the master branch, you'll need to either commit them or [shelve](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-git-shelve-changes-and-save-local-files-with-stash) them with a [stash](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-use-a-git-stash-name-for-an-easy-pop-or-apply).